# How do I run an SQL file in PostgreSQL using a Linux terminal?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am working as a software tester. I want to to test my project locally. So I want to insert the database using the `psql` command. I tried so many times. I couldn't get to access the login page.

This is what I did:

```
postgres@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen$ psql -U admin docmgr

Password for user admin:  psql (9.5.4) Type "help" for help.

docmgr=> psql docmgr -f /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql -U admin
docmgr-> \dt No relations found.

docmgr-> \dt No relations found.

docmgr-> select * from admin_users;

ERROR:  syntax error at or
 near "psql" LINE 1: psql docmgr -f
 /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/st...
         ^
```

Comment: contents: sql create table queries. Does not get any error. It shows nothing. When I select a list of table "\dt " . It shows no relation found. I think the command is not working..

Comment: The title says "How to dump the sql files *in* postgres ...", although in your question, you seem to ask "How to dump the sql files *into* postgres ...". So, what is it? Get data out of Postgres, or get data into Postgres?

Comment: My hypothesis: the file contains the text `-- These are not the dumps you are looking for.` Not very likely, but it fits with the information we've been given.

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

> ```
> docmgr=> psql docmgr -f /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql
> ```

You are running `psql` from within `psql` but "psql" is not a SQL statement.

You either need to run directly from the command prompt:

```
postgres@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen$ psql -U admin -d docmgr -f /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql
```

Or from **within** `psql` you need to use the `\i` command to run a SQL script:

```
postgres@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen$ psql -U admin docmgr

Password for user admin:  psql (9.5.4) Type "help" for help.

docmgr=> \i /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql
```

Comment: postgres@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen$  psql -U admin -d docmgr -f /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql
Password for user admin: 
/var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql: No such file or directory
postgres@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen$ psql -U admin docmgr
Password for user admin: 
psql (9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.

docmgr=> \i /var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql
/var/www/html/docmgr/application/assets/dd/structs/docmgr_21Oct2016.sql: No such file or directory
docmgr=>

Comment: Hai.. there is a one more issue.  It is insert but when I put username and password. It could not access why?