# import .sql file into postgres using psql

Tags: postgresql

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (10.6)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
     8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
     page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.



postgres=#  create database mydb;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=#  psql -d mydb -f Telnet.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql -d mydb -f Telnet.sql;
    ^postgres=#
```

/*I am not able to figure out the error
I have tried a number of other commands as well but I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run an SQL file in PostgreSQL using a Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214589/how-do-i-run-an-sql-file-in-postgresql-using-a-linux-terminal)

Comment: You are trying to run the `psql` command line while already being connected to the database through psql. You have to come out (run `\q`)and execute that command from your host machine's command prompt.

Answer (score 7):

You are already running `psql` so you can only execute [SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) or [psql specific](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) commands

To connect to the newly created database use the `psql` command `\c`:

```
postgres=# \c mydb
```

The prompt should then change to

```
mydb=#
```

To run a SQL script from *within* `psql` use the `psql` command `\i`

```
mydb=# \i Telnet.sql
```

Note that `psql` commands (those starting with `\`) are **not** terminated with `;` - that is only necessary for SQL commands.

Comment: You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "postgres".
mydb=#  \i Telnet.sql;
Telnet.sql: No such file or directory
mydb=#